# How do I just pull the date and time from this line?

Tags: powershell

How do I go about pulling the date and time from this line of a log file? The original is:

```
Build started 6/4/2015 11:25:47 AM.
```

This code gets me most of the way:

```
$x = (Get-Content C:\Users\myusername\Documents\SQLScripts\TestLogs\Lab1.log)[0]
"'" + $x.SubString($x.IndexOf(' ')+1, ($x.LastIndexOf(' ')-$x.IndexOf(' '))-1) + "'"
```

But my output still includes "started"

```
'started 6/4/2015 11:25:47'
```

It seems I don't know how to use the IndexOf command correctly.

Comment: If your `Build started` is a static string, drop it via `-replace "Build started ",""`, otherwise you'll need to split your string by spaces and take 3 last values from the resultant array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `-match`, you can start with:

```
type "log.txt" `
  | where { $_ -match "([0-9]+/[0-9]+/[0-9]+ [0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ (AM|PM))" } `
  | foreach { $matches[0] }
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the type to a variable referencing a file path such as $FileLocation? I don't want to change this in more than one spot in my program.

Comment: replace `log.txt` with `$file = "log.txt"`, and `type $file ...`.

Comment: Do I want `type = $file = "log.txt"` all on the same line?

Comment: You'd want `$file = "log.txt"` on the first line and `type $file` (Including the backtick) on the second line